# Updating state from the data that was read from redux in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-state

Here's an Education Component that I have built for a project. Currently, the education_data is read from the redux state on the second rerender. I aim to add a Visibility Button with every separate entry within the education_data. Education_data is an array of objects. The button will allow the user to hide the data linked to the index they wish to hide. I have another variable called education_vis that stores an array of the size of the education_data with true values initially which needs to be saved into the state to hide the elements on the render. This saving using useState isn't in sync with the data being read from the redux data grabbed using useSelector.
The handleChange works fine only thing needed is to replicate the data within the education_vis into a state so I can use it in the ternary operator to be able to hide the components.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import * as educationActions from "../../actions/educationActions";
import DeleteButton from "./deleteButton";
import UpdateButton from "./updateButton";
import VisibilityOffIcon from '@material-ui/icons/VisibilityOff';
import {  BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import EducationForm  from "../forms/updateForms/educationForm";

const Education = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
      useEffect(() => {
        const userEducation = async () => {
          await dispatch(educationActions.getEducation('60fcc884bbed863d20b02573'));
        };
        userEducation();
      }, [dispatch]);
     const education_data = useSelector((state) => state.education.education);
     var education_vis = Array(education_data.length);
     if(education_vis[0] === undefined){
      for(var i = 0; i < education_data.length; i++){
        education_vis[i] = true;
      }
     } 

    
    const handleChange = (index) => {
      education_vis[index] = !education_vis[index];
      console.log(education_vis);
    }

    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
            <p> Education </p>
            <hr />
            {education_data.map((value, index) => {
              return ( 
              <div>  
                <VisibilityOffIcon onClick = {()=>handleChange(index)} />
                  {education_vis[index] ? <div key={index}>
                    <p>{ value.university_name }, { value.university_city }, { value.university_state }  { value.month_begin } { value.year_begin } - { value.month_end } { value.year_end }</p>
                    <p>{ value.degree_name } in { value.domain_name } { value.GPA }</p>
                    <DeleteButton elementId = { value._id } page = { "Education" }/>
                    <Link to={ `/education/${value._id}/update` } ><UpdateButton /></Link>
                  </div> : null}
              </div>
              )
            })}
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/education/:elementId/update">
          <EducationForm />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    )
}

export default Education
```

Here's how the sample education_data looks. The education_vis for the same would be [true, true]

```
/* var education_data = [
  { 
    degree_name: "Masters",
    domain_name: "Information Sciences and Technology",
    school_name: "iSchool",
    university_name: "Rochester Institute of Technology",
    university_city: "Rochester",
    university_state: "NY",
    university_country: "USA",
    year_begin: "2019",
    month_begin: "August",
    year_end: "2021",
    month_end: "December",
    GPA: "3.8",
  },{
    degree_name: "Bachelors",
    domain_name: "CS",
    school_name: "DSCE",
    university_name: "VTU",
    university_city: "Bangalore",
    university_state: "Karnataka",
    university_country: "India",
    year_begin: "2014",
    month_begin: "August",
    year_end: "2018",
    month_end: "June",
    GPA: "3.8",
}] */
```

Here's how I was trying to set the state using useStates().

```
     const [educationVisibility, setEducationVisibility] = useState(education_vis);
     useEffect(() => {
      setEducationVisibility(education_vis)
   },[education_vis])
```

I am trying to achieve hide/ show functionality for the components on clicking the . For that, I need to upload the education_vis to the state that will enable rerendering of the components and need help for doing that.

Comment: Hello. What is the question? As in, what are you actually trying to achieve and what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: I am trying to achieve hide/ show functionality for the components on clicking the <VisibilityOfIcon />. For that, I need to upload the education_vis to the state that will enable rerendering of the components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mutating `education_vis` when you do `education_vis[index] === !education_vis[index]`. So now the `useEffect` is not going to trigger because `education_vis` never *changed*. It just got *mutated* so the reference of the object is still the same.

React essentially uses`Object.is` over the dependencies to compare depdendency values, so it will return false and hence the code within that `useEffect` will not be run.

Also, I see you are using a `useEffect` for this but you don't need to, since you already have a `handleChange` callback. You can just update the state from there.

```js
const [educationVisibility, setEducationVisibility] = useState(education_vis);
const handleChange = (index) => {
  education_vis[index] = !education_vis[index];
  
  setEducationVisibility([...education_vis]); // using spread to get a new instance of the array
}
```

You can also use [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) library to help you with some of these operations. But that is, if you really need it. It does help when you have complex data structures.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to achieve what I was desired using what you suggested and setState callbacks.